# Convert Pandas DataFrame to & from In-Memory Feather

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, feather, apache-arrow

Using the  [IO tools in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-feather) it is possible to convert a `DataFrame` to an in-memory feather buffer:

```
import pandas as pd  
from io import BytesIO 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3.0,4.0]})  

buf = BytesIO()

df.to_feather(buf)
```

However, using the same buffer to convert back to a DataFrame

```
pd.read_feather(buf)
```

Results in an error:

> ArrowInvalid: Not a feather file

**How can a DataFrame be convert to an in-memory feather representation and, correspondingly, back to a DataFrame?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: @EdChum The documentation explicitly named the variable as `path` which would indicate it was purposeful since all of the other methods name the variable `filepath_or_buffer`.

Comment: Hmm, could you try `buf = io.BytesIO()`

Comment: @EdChum That seems to have worked!

Comment: Looking at the impl it accepts a file path, so it will also accept a file like object so I tried `buf = io.BytesIO()` but I don't have `feather-format` library installed so just waiting for `pip` to complete before confirming

Comment: This does seem to work but I'm not familiar with feather files so can't confirm if all is OK

Comment: @EdChum I tried to verify by converting the feather back to a dataframe but got another error.  Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I get the same problem I've not investigated how to convert the bytes object to a file like object so that pandas can read it again.

Comment: I think this maybe something to ask on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) as it maybe functionality that could be added

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `pandas==0.25.2` this can be accomplished in the following way:

```py
import pandas
import io
df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3.0, 4.0]})
buf = io.BytesIO()
df.to_feather(buf)
output = pandas.read_feather(buf)
```

Then a call to `output.head(2)` returns:

```
    a    b
 0  1  3.0
 1  2  4.0
```

Note that you could do the same with `csv` files, but would require you to use `StringIO` instead of `BytesIO`

---

If you have a `DataFrame` with multiple indexes, you may see an error like

> ValueError: feather does not support serializing <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> for the index; you can .reset_index()to make the index into column(s)

In which case you need to call `.reset_index()` before `to_feather`, and call `.set_index([...])` after `read_feather`

---

Last thing I would like to add, is that if you are doing something with the `BytesIO`, you need to seek back to 0 after writing the feather bytes. For example:

```py
buffer = io.BytesIO()
df.reset_index(drop=False).to_feather(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
s3_client.put_object(Body=buffer, Bucket='bucket', Key='file')
```